# Estimate Power Consumption Based on Running Time Analysis / Code Size

Tags: c, performance, energy

I've developed and tested a C program on my PC and now I want to give an estimate of the power consumption required for the program to do a single run. I've analysised the running time of the application and of invidiual function calls within the application and I know the code size both in assembly lines, but also raw C lines.

How would I give an estimate of the power consumption based on the performance analysis and/code size? I suppose it scales with the amount of lines that uses the CPU for computations or does memory access but I was hoping for a more precise answer.

Also, how would I tell the difference between the power consumption on say my PC compared to a on a microchip device?

Comment: @Mike - I don't believe anyone can delete comments except the person who posted it and moderators. Also, why would non-males be more offended by that joke (which, by the way, is also an answer in one of the "fun" questions that gets revived occasionally) than males?

Comment: The message in his profile was one of the responses to the 'What is the best programming quote' question on SO.

Comment: These comments seemes rather out of context and irrelevant for the topic? Did someone delete a comment above yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a paper on Intel's website that gives [average energy per instruction](http://www.intel.com/pressroom/kits/core2duo/pdf/epi-trends-final2.pdf) for various processors. They give 11 nJ per instruction for Core Duo, for example. How useful that'll be for you depends on how much your code looks like the SpecInt benchmark, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck. What you want to do is pretty much impossible on a desktop PC. Best you could probably do would be to measure the from-the-wall power draw at idle, and when running your program, with as few other programs as possible running at the same time. Average the results over 100 or so runs, and you should have a value with accuracy of a few percent (standard statistical disclaimers apply).

On a Microchip device, it should be easier to calculate the power consumption, since they publish (average) power consumption values for the various modes, and the timing is deterministic. Unfortunately, there are so many differences between a processor like that and your desktop processor (word size, pipelining, multiple-issue, multiple processes, etc, etc) that there really won't be any effective way to compare the two.

Comment: I know other people doing the same task has found approximation formulas for the power consumption based on the number of executed assymbly lines of code. I'm not looking for anything precise, just a general approximation of the power c.