# How to calculate energy consumption (joules) of java code in Windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans-10

i write a code in netbeans and want to find the how much energy consumed when i run this code but i don't know how to calculate

i searched jRAPL tool but its only useful in linux environment.
i don't want tools to calculate energy consumption i just want to calculate energy consumption of that particular code
i have tried netbean profiler but profiler did not give me required results.

This is just as an example

```
for(double i=0;i<500000;i++) {
       System.out.print("Test Purpose");
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the netbeans profiler and write a custom configuration: https://profiler.netbeans.org/ https://profiler.netbeans.org/docs/help/5.5/custom_configurations.html

Comment: That code is going to use ~0 energy, compared to everything else you have running.

Comment: Note that modern processors also use energy to idle, as the clock signal still need to reach the internals of every core, reducing the clock speed is a great way to save on power

Comment: is there any way to compute energy consumption of code that are running in netbean?

Comment: give me answer please????

Comment: [1] You might want to delete your most recent comment which is likely to dissuade people from helping you. [2] Have you looked at [jRAPL -- A framework for profiling energy consumption of Java programs](http://kliu20.github.io/jRAPL/)? That link provides an example of doing exactly what you want. I didn't see any mention of it being restricted to use on Linux. [3] Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392233/2985643) to another SO question [Is it possible to extract instruction specific energy consumption in a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51390641/2985643).